# Does NFC permission result in an error when the device has no support?

Tags: android, nfc

I have taken NFC permission in `AndroidManifest.xml` and I uploded my app to PlayStore. Now My question is, if device doest not support NFC and I try to install `app` from playstore. Does it gives an any kind of error? Does `app` atleast install on that device. I don't have any non supported NFC devices to test this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> device doesn't not support NFC and I try to install app from
>   playstore. Does it give any kind of error?

Play Store won't give any error and will let the users install the app, if you have not mentioned the relevant `uses-feature` tag in manifest file. Now, once installed, while trying to get `NfcManager` instance, it'd be **null**. Refer to this [doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc#manifest) on how to request NFC access.

`NfcManager manager = (NfcManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NFC_SERVICE); // null`

The better practice, here, is that we should include `uses-feature` in manifest file to let Play Store know that our app has certain hardware dependency and we don't want the app to be available for the devices which do not consist of this set of hardware(defined in `uses-feature` tag).

For example:

```
<uses-feature 
     android:name="android.hardware.nfc" 
     android:required="true"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

there is:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC"/>
```

and there is:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" android:required="true"/>
```

`uses-feature` can be used to control the behavior (eg. only permit install on devices with NFC).

if you require a test-device without `NFC` support, just use an emulator image.

only rather outdated hardware devices do not support it - and the most elegant solution might be to set `android:required="false"` and then check, if the sensor is even present, at runtime - in order to make it an optional feature, in case it would make sense, based upon what the app is actually doing.